# How to send periodic emails

Tags: shell, scripting

How to set a specific day (lets say Friday) to send an email by using mail command  shell script?

I need logic for send a mail only on weekly once for example (Friday) by using shell script.

```
mailx -s  "Subject $DATE " -r "resource"  -a $LOG  a@gmail.com < status
```

This mail send mail daily?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `cron`

Comment: You can use crontab.You can set which day dan which time to send email.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/cron/info

Answer (score 2):

To do a task repeatedly you need to setup a cron job. To do that let's first create a script of the task you want to perform.

Create file named (for eg. mail.sh) where enter the following:

> #!/bin/bash
>
> mailx -s "Subject $DATE " -r "resource" -a $LOG a@gmail.com < status

Save the file. Assign the script execution permission by typing in terminal:

> $ chmod +x mail.sh

Run the script `./mail.sh` to make sure it works.

Now the script won't automatically run every Friday. For that install `crontab`.

> $ sudo apt install crontab

Now type in terminal:

> $ crontab -e

Select your favorite editor and append the line at the end. ( First refer link below)

> 0 0 * * 5 mylocation/mail.sh

The above code will run mail.sh every Friday indicated by 5 at 12.00 Am sharp indicated by 0 0.

Please refer to the [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) to learn about crontab. You can google crontab too. I recommend you to learn about using crontab and only append the line.